# How to override css code in custom class?

Tags: css

I'm working on some css code from my client. Below is some of css code.

```
.quick-stats {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;

    > h5 {
        color: #fff;
        float: left;                
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        letter-spacing: 0.3px;
        line-height: 22px;
        margin:5px 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }

    > ul {
        list-style: outside none none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;

        > li {
            float: left;
            padding: 0 1px;
            width: 33.333%;
```

I can assign class like `<div class="quick-stats">`. But I would like to change `li width` by override code in style from `width: 33.333%;` to `width: 50%;`. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: For an individual element, or for each element with the class `.quick-stats`?

Comment: Dear Obsidian Age, only li element that belong to quick-stats class.

Comment: I get that. I'm asking if you want to change the `width` from `33.333%` to `50%` for *one* `.quick-stats`, or if you want to change the `width` of *every* element with the class `.quick-stats`? If you want to do it for every element, why not simply alter the code above to be `50` instead of `33.333`?

Comment: Dear Obsidian Age, Sorry for confustion. Answer is just only one.

Comment: Give `.quick-stats` element an id, then `#quick-statsID ul li { width: 50%}`

Comment: Dear Robin, I tried <div class="quick-stats ul li { width: 50%}"> but not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking to override one element, then you have two options.

Either make use of inline styles by adding the style to the `<li>` element itself:

```
<div class="quick-stats">
  <li style="width: 50%;"></li>
  <li></li>
</div>
```

Or give the element a second class with more [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/):

```
<div class="quick-stats">
  <li class="wide"></li>
  <li></li>
</div>

.quick-stats > ul > li.wide {
  width: 50%;
}
```

The latter approach has the benefit that you can have multiple elements make use of the new class.

Alternatively, you could also make use of a pseudo-class such as **[`nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)** to target a specific element:

```
<div class="quick-stats">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</div>

.quick-stats > ul > li:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

With any of the three approaches, other `.quick-stats` elements will still retain their original `33.333%` `width`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think it is one of the `<li>` elements he wants to be 50%, if that were the case he can add the class directly to `<li class="wide">` or he could add an extra rule to the style sheet like `> li:nth-child(3){ width:50%; }`

Comment: @andrew -- True; got a bit confused there. My apologies. Bear with me while I update the answer.

Comment: Dear Obsidian Age, I would like to change LI's width instead of div's width. This LI is belong to quick-stats class. I tried <div class="quick-stats ul li { width: 50%}"> but not work.

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution - My apologies; I misunderstood at first. I've just updated my answer; please try the new solutions :)

Comment: Dear Obsidian Age - Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1. The first and easy solution is just to use the inline style
2. You can nest it inside another class name to override it.
3. Target the element itself by its class name. (You can also mark it as important in some cases.)